# In Nginx, should I tune worker_processes to CPU cores or CPUs?

Tags: nginx

I'm confused from the articles I read.

Should I set the amount of worker_processes in Nginx to:
Amount of CPUs (`grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l` displays 2)

or to the amount of CPU cores? (`nproc` displays 8)

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of hardware do you have? On my i3770K/Debian/Sid both commands give 8...

Comment: Thank for reply. I use a VPS from Servermania.com. It's with Debian6.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the fine manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_processes)

> The optimal value depends on many factors including (but not limited
>   to) the number of CPU cores, the number of hard disk drives that store
>   data, and load pattern. When one is in doubt, setting it to the number
>   of available CPU cores would be a good start (the value “auto” will
>   try to autodetect it).

However, that assumes that there is no other processing on the server. If you were also running other processes on that server then you should probably reserve CPUs for those processes.

There's also probably a very real probability in diminishing returns for assigning 8 cores to Nginx. You be better off setting it to only 4, and then only increasing it if you can identify a need to have more worker processes running.